# android: ViewPager with more than 100 webview

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpage

I've viewpager that has 604 webviews and i want to load 5 pages every time that user scrolling the pager, like that:

{...[4][5][6][7][8]...}

I assume that the current page that selected by user is page 6, so i want to load 2 pages before and after the selected one. I used this built-in method `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)` and it doesn't run as expected!

so, any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with so many complex Fragments you should make sure to use a [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html).

To load two pages ahead also set `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)` instead of `3`.

You also should make sure that in the `getItem()` method of the adapter the `fragments will only be created as needed`.

Comment: thnaks @Konstantin i'll give it a try :)

Comment: hi, i don't know how can i return 2 fragments or more in the getItem() method?!